# What is SOAP Request Body for Sabre hotel reservation API [ OTA_HotelResLLSRQ ]

Tags: sabre

I am working hotel reservation work flow. But I struggled on Hotel Reservation API. Below I mentioned step by step activities what I done. Pls help me to solve the issue.

1. I Searched New York ["NYC"] city hotels using OTA_HotelAvailRQ API and got the successful response.
2. From that response picked hotel code [ HotelCode="0048286" ] property and supplied to HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ api then successful response gotted.
3. From that response picked first RPH attribute of room rate element from room rates element   [ < RoomRates > < RoomRate RPH="001" > ] and supplied to the OTA_HotelResLLSRQ API.
4. But following error happend. Workflows are tested in SoapUI.

```xml
<stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2016-08-20T03:19:25-05:00">
                   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                      <stl:Message>FORMAT</stl:Message>
                      <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
             </stl:ApplicationResults>
```

1. OTA_HotelAvailRQ API :

Request Body : 
`<ns:OTA_HotelAvailRQ Version="2.2.1">
        <ns:AvailRequestSegment>
            <ns:Customer>
                <ns:Corporate>
                    <ns:ID>ABC1223</ns:ID>
                </ns:Corporate>
            </ns:Customer>
            <ns:GuestCounts Count="2" />
            <ns:HotelSearchCriteria>
                <ns:Criterion>
                    <ns:HotelRef HotelCityCode="NYC" />
                </ns:Criterion>
            </ns:HotelSearchCriteria>
            <ns:TimeSpan End="09-24" Start="09-22" />
        </ns:AvailRequestSegment>
    </ns:OTA_HotelAvailRQ>`

Response Body or Soap Body :

`<OTA_HotelAvailRS Version="2.2.1" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
         <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
            <stl:Success timeStamp="2016-08-20T03:07:02-05:00"/>
         </stl:ApplicationResults>
         <AdditionalAvail Ind="true"/>
         <AvailabilityOptions>
            <AvailabilityOption RPH="001">
               <BasicPropertyInfo AreaID="000E" ChainCode="WV" Distance="M" GEO_ConfidenceLevel="1" HotelCityCode="JFK" HotelCode="0048286" HotelName="HOTEL ON RIVINGTON" Latitude="40.719970" Longitude="-73.987990">
                  <Address>
                     <AddressLine>107 RIVINGTON STREET</AddressLine>
                     <AddressLine>NEW YORK NY 10002</AddressLine>
                  </Address>
                  <ContactNumbers>
                     <ContactNumber Fax="1-212-475 5959" Phone="1-212-475 2600"/>
                  </ContactNumbers>
                  <DirectConnect>
                     <Alt_Avail Ind="false"/>
                     <DC_AvailParticipant Ind="true"/>
                     <DC_SellParticipant Ind="true"/>
                     <RatesExceedMax Ind="false"/>
                     <UnAvail Ind="false"/>
                  </DirectConnect>
                  <LocationDescription Code="G">
                     <Text>NEW YORK</Text>
                  </LocationDescription>
                  <Property Rating="NTM">
                     <Text>4 CROWN</Text>
                  </Property>
                  <PropertyOptionInfo>
                     <!-- deleted -->
                  </PropertyOptionInfo>
                  <RoomRate RateLevelCode="RAC">
                     <AdditionalInfo>
                        <CancelPolicy Numeric="00"/>
                     </AdditionalInfo>
                     <HotelRateCode>RAC</HotelRateCode>
                  </RoomRate>
                  <SpecialOffers Ind="false"/>
               </BasicPropertyInfo>
            </AvailabilityOption>
           <!-- 6 More Results are avilable below i skipped -->
         </AvailabilityOptions>
      </OTA_HotelAvailRS>
   </soap-env:Body>`

2. HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ

Request Body :

`<SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns4:HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v120" xmlns:ns3="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:ns4="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" Version="2.3.0">
            <ns4:AvailRequestSegment>
                <ns4:GuestCounts Count="2" />
                <ns4:HotelSearchCriteria>
                    <ns4:Criterion>
                        <ns4:HotelRef HotelCode="0048286" />
                    </ns4:Criterion>
                </ns4:HotelSearchCriteria>
               <ns4:TimeSpan End="09-24" Start="09-22" />
            </ns4:AvailRequestSegment>
        </ns4:HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>`

Response Body :

`<soap-env:Body>
      <HotelPropertyDescriptionRS Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
         <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
            <stl:Success timeStamp="2016-08-20T03:11:53-05:00"/>
         </stl:ApplicationResults>
         <RoomStay>
            <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="WV" GeoConfidenceLevel="1" HotelCityCode="JFK" HotelCode="0048286" HotelName="HOTEL ON RIVINGTON" Latitude="40.719970" Longitude="-73.987990" NumFloors="20" RPH="001">
               <Address>
                  <AddressLine>107 RIVINGTON STREET</AddressLine>
                  <AddressLine>NEW YORK NY 10002</AddressLine>
                  <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
               </Address>
               <Awards>
                  <AwardProvider>NTM4 CROWN</AwardProvider>
               </Awards>
               <CheckInTime>16:00</CheckInTime>
               <CheckOutTime>12:00</CheckOutTime>
               <ContactNumbers>
                  <ContactNumber Fax="1-212-475 5959" Phone="1-212-475 2600"/>
               </ContactNumbers>
               <DirectConnect Ind="false">
                 <!--I deleted -->
               </DirectConnect>
               <IndexData>
                  <!--I deleted -->
               </IndexData>
               <PropertyOptionInfo>
                 <!--I deleted -->
               </PropertyOptionInfo>
               <PropertyTypeInfo>
                  <!--I deleted -->
               </PropertyTypeInfo>
               <SpecialOffers Ind="false"/>
               <Taxes>
                  <Text>8.5PCT ST</Text>
                  <Text>6.25PCT CT</Text>
                  <Text>3USD OCC</Text>
               </Taxes>
               <VendorMessages>
                  <!--I deleted -->
               </VendorMessages>
            </BasicPropertyInfo>
            <Guarantee>
               <!-- I delete -->
            </Guarantee>
            <LongSellTimeIdentifier>D138CA674B4C40A4529719A000000000529719A016233031153</LongSellTimeIdentifier>
            <RoomRates>
               <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="C1KRAC" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="001" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
                  <AdditionalInfo>
                    <!-- deleted -->
                  </AdditionalInfo>
                  <Rates>
                     <Rate Amount="550.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
                        <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
                           <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="1">
                              <Charges ExtraPerson="50.00"/>
                           </AdditionalGuestAmount>
                        </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
                        <HotelTotalPricing Amount="1269.25">
                           <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
                           <TotalTaxes Amount="169.25">
                              <TaxFieldOne>162.26</TaxFieldOne>
                              <TaxFieldThree>3.00</TaxFieldThree>
                              <TaxFieldTwo>3.99</TaxFieldTwo>
                              <Text>STATETAX</Text>
                              <Text>OTHER</Text>
                              <Text>OTHER</Text>
                           </TotalTaxes>
                        </HotelTotalPricing>
                     </Rate>
                  </Rates>
               </RoomRate>
              <!-- I deleted Room Rate from RPH="002" to RPH="0025" -->
            </RoomRates> 
            <TimeSpan Duration="0005" End="2016-09-24" Start="2016-09-22"/>
         </RoomStay>
      </HotelPropertyDescriptionRS>
   </soap-env:Body>`

3. OTA_HotelResLLSRQ

Request Body :

`<ns2:OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:ns3="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v120" xmlns:ns4="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.2.0">
            <ns2:Hotel>
                <ns2:BasicPropertyInfo RPH="001">
                    <ns2:ConfirmationNumber>ABC123</ns2:ConfirmationNumber>
                </ns2:BasicPropertyInfo>
                <ns2:Guarantee Type="GDPST">
                    <ns2:CC_Info>
                        <ns2:PaymentCard Code="AX" ExpireDate="2020-12" Number="1234567890" />
                        <ns2:PersonName>
                            <ns2:Surname>TEST</ns2:Surname>
                        </ns2:PersonName>
                    </ns2:CC_Info>
                </ns2:Guarantee>
                <ns2:GuestCounts Count="2" />
                <ns2:RoomType NumberOfUnits="1"/>
                <ns2:TimeSpan End="09-24T10:00" Start="09-22T08:00" />
            </ns2:Hotel>
        </ns2:OTA_HotelResRQ>`

Response Body :

`<OTA_HotelResRS Version="2.2.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
         <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2016-08-20T03:19:25-05:00">
               <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                  <stl:Message>FORMAT</stl:Message>
                  <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
               </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
         </stl:ApplicationResults>
      </OTA_HotelResRS>`

Pls provide working Request Body for OTA_HotelResLLSRQ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried requesting with a real test Credit Card?

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Comment: FYI 4111111111111111 always validates as a Visa by passing the luhn algorithm. That's my go to.

Answer (score 0):

The credit card number "1234567890" is likely the cause of the problem. If this is being done on Sabre's production API, a real credit card number is required here. You should also enter the card owner's real surname instead of "TEST".

My recommendation would be to enter a real valid credit number and expiry date. To prevent the booking from getting passed to the hotel, you should make a call to "IgnoreTransactionLLSRQ" right after the call to "OTA_HotelResLLSRQ".

The SOAP body for "IgnoreTransactionLLSRQ" is very simple:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <IgnoreTransactionRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.0"></IgnoreTransactionRQ>
</soapenv:Body>
```

That will allow you to pass a valid credit card to "OTA_HotelResLLSRQ" to verify if that is the cause of your error. Once your flow is working properly, you can then replace the call to "IgnoreTransactionLLSRQ" with the proper "EndTransactionLLSRQ" to generate real bookings.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The credit card number is too short and invalid. The roomrate should have included a list of accepted cards, maybe AX is not accepted. Also it probably won't accept a name like TEST.